# Using Socket.IO in server side with socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, websocket, socket.io

I use the socket.io in my app.js and configure it with express framework, now when I run the application both of application and socket.io will start and I can emit messages between client and app.js.

app.js (Server)

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.creatServer(app),
    socket = require('socket.io'),
    io = socket.listen(server);

server.listen(3000);    

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('message', function(msg){
        io.sockets.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var server = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
    server.emit('message', 'Hello World');
</script>
```

But I want to use socket in other Controllers... I use "socket.io-client (https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io-client)", now I want to get messages 
that emitted from app.js to all sockets.

controller.js (Server)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client'),
    socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1', {
        port: 3000
    });

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('CONNECTED!!');
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log("New message:", msg);
    });
});
```

It can't connect!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care who gets the messages, you can do a global broadcast from socket.io. That works inside controllers.

Comment: if I use different port for socket.io it works! but if I set application port in socket, it doesn't work in controllers... just works in client

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the client socket to emit. io is the socket.io instance not the client socket that connected.

in server

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('message', function(msg){
      client.emit('message', msg);
  });
});
```

if you need to broadcast, then you can use the io instance

```
io.socket.sockets.emit('message', msg);
```

Comment: I can emit messages between app.js (server) and client using io.sockets.emit, client.emit or client.broadcast.emit but I want to emit some messages between app.js (server) and for example chat controller (server).
if my socket.io port was different from application port it was successfully worked and I can emit message between server controllers and client... but in this example I use same port for application and socket.io

Answer (score 0):

```
var io = require('../socket/sio').initialize(server);
app.set('socketio', io)
```

and in your controller :

```
var io = req.app.get('socketio');
io.to(socketId).emit('sendData', data);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.